# how to sorting date in array C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a date in the form of ddmmyyyy in array

```
    int checkIn[n], checkOut[n];
    int a = sizeof(checkIn) / sizeof(checkIn[0]);
    int a2 = sizeof(checkOut) / sizeof(checkOut[0]);
    
    sort(checkIn, checkIn + a);
    sort(checkOut, checkOut + a2);
```

Input:

```
3
08022022 15022022
10022025 14022025
15032022 20032022
```

Output:

```
8022022 10022025 15032022
```

How to fix. Thank you

Comment: Change int to char

Comment: Looks like first column is sorted correctly as you passed it (array of numbers). Not sure why you store date as integer. Could you post how you read data and what is expected result?

Comment: Do you have a function which, for two inputs, tells which one is "greater" than the other? You are using integers for your dates, so can we assume that you are fine with sorting mostly by day, then by month then by year? In that case, what is wrong about the shown output? It seems to be correct.

Comment: Thanks for the comment so should I change the format of the data collection?

Comment: If I change date with array 2 dimension. it will be better?

Comment: Depends what you want to achieve. Is there any reason why you want date in that format instead of e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point ?

Comment: Thank you very much, I decided to change the format to dd-mm-yyyy. Please give me some advice on how to sort and how to store.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best idea to solve this date sort in C++ is to use this struct:

```
struct tm {
   int tm_sec;   // seconds of minutes from 0 to 61
   int tm_min;   // minutes of hour from 0 to 59
   int tm_hour;  // hours of day from 0 to 24
   int tm_mday;  // day of month from 1 to 31
   int tm_mon;   // month of year from 0 to 11
   int tm_year;  // year since 1900
   int tm_wday;  // days since sunday
   int tm_yday;  // days since January 1st
   int tm_isdst; // hours of daylight savings time
}
```

You should load the dates you want to sort in this struct and then you can use mktime() to get the time_t for using the following function:

```
double difftime (time_t end, time_t beginning);
```

(https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/difftime/)

This function will calculate the difference between the time_t's. Then you can sort the list or the array. For example for the list you can do: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/